# A confusion of direct Sum in finite dimensional vector space

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite -dimensional vector space and $T:V \to V$ be linear.Prove that $V$ is the direct sum of $R(T)$ and $N(T)$ if $V=R(T)+N(T)$.
My try...Let $N'(T)$ be the subspace of $V$  normal to the plane of $N(T)$, Then $N(T)$ and $N'(T)$ forms direct sum of V.Hence $N'(T)$ contained in $R(T)$.From the definition of direct sum we can conclude dimension of $N'(T)=dim(V)-dim(W)=dimR(T)$.(by rank nullity theorem). Both the sub spaces $R(T)$ and $N'(T)$ has same dimensions and 2nd subspace is contained in the 1st subspace .So they are the same sub spaces and I conclude that $V$ is the direct sum of $R(T)$ and $N(T)$...Am I correct?Probably I have made my problem too complicated.

Comment: You know (are given) that $V=R(T)+N(T)$. So what do you need to show to prove the sum is a direct sum?

Comment: There interestion is zero

Comment: Actually I uses if V is the  sum of A and B and also direct sum of A and C,then C is contained in B,It's my intuition, Am I wrong?

Comment: You define $N'(T)$ to be the normal subspace, but then you have a hidden assumption that your vector space has a defined inner product, something that generally isn't true. Thus, you need to find another, more general proof.

Comment: (Your first comment) Yes, that the intersection $R(T)\cap N(t)$ is $\{ 0 \}$. Maybe you can use the rank-nullity theorem for that?

Comment: A direct sum need not be orthogonal. So, if $V$ is $\mathbb{R}^2$ it can be the direct sum of $A$ and $B$ where $A$ and $B$ are two straight lines that intersect at the origin at an angle of $20^\circ$, say. But then $C$ can be a third line that intersects $A$ in the origin at another angle, say $40^\circ$. Then $V=A\oplus B$ and also $V=A\oplus C$, but $C$ is not contained in $B$ (and $B$ not in $C$).

Comment: @Jeppe sting Nielsen I was trying in this way but falied,But it is the better approach as you said.

Comment: Yes,sorry...My idea is wrong

Comment: Instead, use a well known theorem about the dimension of $S+T$ given the dimension of $S$ and $T$.

Comment: You are right, it will not work with the orthogonal complement (your $N'(T)$ space of all normal vectors to $N(T)$). Aston Villa is right, when you know $V=R+N$ and know that the dimensions are right, $\dim V = \dim R + \dim N$, you need to conclude that the sum is direct, $R\oplus N$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to show $N(T) \cap R(T) = \{0\}$, as $N(T) + R(T) = V$ is already given.
We know by the rank-nullity theorem that $\dim(N(T)) + \dim(R(T)) = \dim(V) = n$.

We know by the standard theorem on sum of vector subspaces (see [this](http://web.iitd.ac.in/~ritumoni/lecture%2011%20&%2012.pdf) for a proof e.g.) that

$$ \dim(N(T) + R(T)) = \dim(N(T) + \dim(R(T)) + \dim(R(T) \cap N(T))$$

Using rank-nullity and $N(T) + R(T) = V$ we get

$$ n = n + \dim(R(T) \cap N(T))$$

so $\dim(R(T) \cap N(T)) = 0$ and so $R(T) \cap N(T) = \{0\}$ as required.